# Missing argument 1 for PostController::postEditPost()

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to make an edit to a database entry,

The database is set up in such a way that I can do rollbacks of posts depending on their version.

I first retrieve the entry from the database:

```
public function getEditPost($id)
{   
    $posts = Post::find($id);
    return View::make('posts.edit')->with('posts', $posts); 
}
```

This is then displayed within a form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/post/editpost/' )) }}
{{ Form::label('content', 'Content') }}
{{ Form::textarea('content', Input::old('content', $posts->content_posts()->first()['content'])) }}
{{ Form::submit('Edit') }}
{{ Form::token() }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The issue comes when I want to make a new entry from the just edited contents, I need to use the ID of the previous post to create the new one with:

```
public function postEditPost($id)
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $posts = Post::find($id);
    $content = Input::get('content');

    $changePost = new ChangePost;
    $contentpost = ContentPost::find($posts);
    $changePost->user()->associate($userId);
    $changePost->content_post()->associate($postId);
    $contentpost->save();

    $postContent = new ContentPost;
    $postContent->content = $content;
    $postContent->post_id = $posts;
    $postContent->post_id = $post->id;
    $postContent->version = 1;
    $postContent->save();

}
```

Here are the two routes:

```
Route::get('/post/editpost/{id}', array('as' => 'post-edit', 'uses' =>       'PostController@getEditPost'));
Route::post('/post/editpost/', array('as' => 'post-edit-post', 'uses' => 'PostController@postEditPost'));
```

How can I pass the ID from the getEditPost to the postEditPost when creating a new entry into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to pass it via route, so you can get it the way to are trying in your controller action:

Change your route to:

```
Route::post('/post/editpost/{id}', array('as' => 'post-edit-post', 'uses' => 'PostController@postEditPost'));
```

And your form open to:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('post-edit-post', $posts->content_posts()->first()->id) )) }}
```